# Prove that $E(\mathbb{C})^{\text{tor}} \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

> Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{C}$.  We know that $E(\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}/L$ (this is a group isomorphism) for some lattice $L \subset \mathbb{C}$.  Using this fact prove that
>
> $$\begin{aligned}
> E(\mathbb{C})^{\text{tor}} \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}
> \end{aligned}$$
>
> Is $E(\mathbb{C})^{\text{tor}}$ a finitely generated abelian group?

I know that to show that those groups are isomorphic, we need to simply construct the mapping of those groups that is the isomorphism.  Some other thoughts that I have is that since $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion, we have $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^{\text{tor}}$, and that working backward i.e. proving that $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \simeq E(\mathbb{C})^{\text{tor}}$ might work.  However, I am stuck because I was not able to find the way to use the fact (that $E(\mathbb{C}) \simeq \mathbb{C}/L$) to prove these isomorphic groups.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: $S^1\times S^1$ has torsion $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $E(\Bbb C)\cong\Bbb C/L$ for a lattice $L$. And $\Bbb C/L$ is isomorphic to...?

(You may be aware that $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is the torsion subgroup of ____)

> $\Bbb C/L\cong (\Bbb R\oplus\Bbb R)/(\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z)\cong(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$), the blank is referring to $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$

Comment: Well, you showed that $\mathbb{C}/L \simeq \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  However, that does not partially nor fully answer the question.  Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: @NasuSama It does.

Comment: @NasuSama I am expecting you to figure out $$(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\times \Bbb R/\Bbb Z)^{\rm tors}=(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z)^{\rm tors}\times(\Bbb R/\Bbb Z)^{\rm tors}=\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$$ on your own!

Comment: Thanks.  Already figured out by myself before you posted.  Guess I shouldn't post too quickly. :)