# Torsion group of elliptic curve isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})^{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

I am reading preliminaries with the goal of learning the proof of Mazur's torsion theorem for elliptic curves.

I have read the fact: $E[m] \cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ for $E$ an elliptic curve over $K$ with $\text{char}(K) = 0$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. And $E[m] \cong (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}/m'\mathbb{Z})$ when $\text{char}(K) = p$ and $m = p^{e}m'$ with $(p, m') = 1$.

There is a corollary: As an abstract group, $E_{\text{tors}} \cong (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ if $\text{char}(K) = 0$, and $E_{\text{tors}} \cong (\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/\mathbb{Z})$ or $E_{\text{tors}} \cong (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \oplus (\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}/\mathbb{Z})$ if $\text{char}(K) = p$.

I almost understand the statement "$E_{\text{tors}} \cong (\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$" from [Prove that $E(\mathbb{C})^{\text{tor}} \cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761076/prove-that-e-mathbbc-texttor-cong-mathbbq-mathbbz-times-mathb), although $K$ is not necessarily $\mathbb{C}$. The second part (when $\text{char}(K) = p$) I do not understand. Apparently it follows immediately from the first statement. Any help or hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be algebraically closed of characteristic $p$, and let $E$ be
an elliptic curve over $K$. Then it is a theorem that the $p$-torsion
$E[p]$ is either isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ ("ordinary") or has
zero order ("supersingular"). In the ordinary case the $p$-power torsion
will be $E[p^\infty]\cong \Bbb Z[1/p]/\Bbb Z$ and in the supersingular
case it will of course be zero. In both cases, when $p\nmid N$, the $N$-torsion is isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z)^2$.

Let's consider the ordinary case. Then $E_{\text{tors}}$ is the
direct sum of the $E[q^\infty]$ over all primes $q$. When $q\ne p$,
$E[q^\infty]\cong(\Bbb Z[1/q]/\Bbb Z)\oplus(\Bbb Z[1/q]/\Bbb Z)$.
So $E_{\text{tors}}$ is the direct sum of two groups $A$ and $B$
with $A\cong\bigoplus_q (\Bbb Z[1/q]/\Bbb Z)$ and
$B\cong\bigoplus_{q\ne p} (\Bbb Z[1/q]/\Bbb Z)$. But $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z\cong A$ and $\Bbb Z_{(p)}/\Bbb Z\cong B$. These are just splitting up these
torsion groups as direct sums of their $q^\infty$-components.

In the supersingular case, you'll get two copies of $B$.

Comment: Can you explain the notation $E[q^{\infty}]$? is this the same as $\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E[q^{n}]$ ? Thank you.

Comment: Just $\bigcup_n E[q^n]$ (it's not a direct sum).

Comment: Okay. I will work out the details. Thanks.